# Stop XSLT Caching

Tags: caching, amazon-web-services

I am currently using the xsl:import tag. However we have noticed it is caching the XSL. This means that when we update the XSL that is being referenced too, we have to refresh each XSL that uses the referenced document.

My question is there a way to stop caching?

Below is an example of the code we are using:

Main XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:import href="errorCode.xsl"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="time_generated"/>
<xsl:template match="/getResponse">
        <response>
                <header>
                        <!-- START - errorCode.xsl Results -->
                        <xsl:call-template name="errorCode"/>
                        <!-- END - errorCode.xsl Results -->
                        <response_detail>
                                <time_generated_unix/>
                                <time_generated_date_time>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="$time_generated"/>
                                </time_generated_date_time>
                        </response_detail>
                        <apikey_detail>
                                <class/>
                                <rate-limit-remaining/>
                                <rate-limit-reset/>
                        </apikey_detail>
                </header>
                <data>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="payload/node()"/>
                </data>
        </response>
</xsl:template>
```

External XSL that is being referenced in the import:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:template name="errorCode">
        <!-- START - SAP Error Codes -->
        <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="rcode = 0">
                        <status>200</status>
                        <message_detail>Test</message_detail>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="rcode = 1">
                        <status>401</status>
                        <message_detail>Unauthorised &#8211; User Does Not exist</message_detail>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="rcode = 3">
                        <status>401</status>
                        <message_detail>Unauthorised &#8211; User is not authorised to perform the
                                operation</message_detail>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="rcode = 4">
                        <status>400</status>
                        <message_detail>Bad request &#8211; No Data could be returned</message_detail>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="rcode = 5">
                        <status>400</status>
                        <message_detail>Bad request &#8211; Invalid Data In request</message_detail>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="rcode = 6">
                        <status>202</status>
                        <message_detail>Request for creation accepted but not yet completed</message_detail>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="rcode = 7">
                        <status>409</status>
                        <message_detail>Conflict - Data is locked in another request</message_detail>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="rcode = 8">
                        <status>400</status>
                        <message_detail>Bad request &#8211; Mandatory Field Not Specified</message_detail>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="rcode = 9">
                        <status>400</status>
                        <message_detail>Bad request &#8211; Data is not unique</message_detail>
                </xsl:when>
                <!-- END - SAP Error Codes -->
                <!-- Catach All Other Error Codes Not Specified -->
                <xsl:otherwise>
                        <status>400</status>
                        <message_detail>SAP Unknown Error</message_detail>
                </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Is it possible to stop the caching by either creating the same functionality another way? Or to insert something into the XSL docs to either refresh or not cache at all?

Many Thanks

Comment: have you tried using `xsl:include`?

Comment: We need more context.  What other language or system are you using to drive the xslt processing?

Comment: It is a pure XSLT conversion. It is running on a server that we can not touch, so everything has to be on via XSLT's. It is going to be converting DB responses and pushing them through a API (Apigee).

I was informed that include does the same thing? Does it not?

Comment: When you say "it" is caching, we need to know what "it" is. To fix the problem, you will need to change some configuration settings for "it". The problem has nothing to do with the specifics of your XSLT code (or with the use of import vs include).

Comment: It is possible that There is something like a "caching resolver" used in the application -- this has nothing to do with XSLT and the complete XSLT question has very littl, if anything to do with XSLT. So the answer to this question is: There might be a way to stop caching or thhe only way to stop caching might be to stop and start the application. To get the exact answer, investigate how the caching resolver implements cache invalidation.

Comment: How are you loading your stylesheets? If you could provide the language and code sample, it will be easier to determine how/why it is being "cached" and how to (re-)load the XSLT source.

Comment: I have just found out that the API sits on top of AWS. Which runs on PHP, which means from my understanding we can selectivly stop the Main XSL from caching the reference XSL; allowing every call to gather the info from the reference XSL for every call.@Mads Hansen - The XSL files are loaded into the Apigee studio, then are deployed on top of AWS. This means that because they are packaged by Apigee, you have little control of how you can interact with. The only things you can alter XSL's JSON Requests, and some other specific Aipgee policies.@Michael Kay - Regarding the "IT", mostly referes t

Comment: @Keevil: This is a first good step. Next you have to communicate with AWS experts. Also, ask the question: What if the main stylesheet itself is modified -- do you have the same caching problem?

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev - If i redeploy the project, it picks up the changes. However i have to do this every time. Which would be fine, but because of the level of security the developers do not have access to Prod, and there are many hoops to jump through to redeploy the project. And it is not a sustainable method.

Comment: @Keevil: Until now you probably have understood that this is not an XSLT question. Could you, please, edit the tags and remove the XSLT tag? I would suggest tagging it with "aws"